# Javascript Drawer Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

Trying to check the width of a position fixed element. Upon the menu-icon-container being clicked, the width of the drawer should increase from 0% to 18%. The drawer should close if the body of the document is clicked, but only if the width of the drawer is 18%. When I tried logging the width of the drawer to the console I got 0px, even though the result is being logged after the drawer is expanded. Does anybody know what I'm missing?

```
$("#menu-icon-container").click(function(){
    $("#drawer-menu-wrapper").animate({width:'18%'},'fast');
    $("#drawer-home-text").text("Home");
    $("#drawer-products-text").text("Products");
    $("#body-wrapper").css("opacity","0.5");
    console.log($("#drawer-menu-wrapper").css("width"));
});
$("#close-icon-container").click(function(){
    $("#drawer-menu-wrapper").animate({width:'0%'},'fast');
    $("#drawer-home-text").text("");
    $("#drawer-products-text").text("");
    $("#body-wrapper").css("opacity","1");
});
$("#body-wrapper").click(function(){
    if ($("#drawer-menu-wrapper").css("width")!="0px"){
        $("#drawer-menu-wrapper").animate({width:'0%'},'fast');
        $("#drawer-home-text").text("");
        $("#drawer-products-text").text("");
        $("#body-wrapper").css("opacity","1");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think you are logging it *after* the drawer is expanded? The code indicates you are dumping the value as soon as the animation starts (not when it ends). Animate operates asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As Gone Coding mentioned:

```
$("#menu-icon-container").click(function(){
    $("#drawer-menu-wrapper").animate({width:'18%'},'fast',function(){
       console.log($("#drawer-menu-wrapper").css("width"));
    });
});
```